# Properly configuring subdirectories with cmake

Tags: linker, cmake

I am currently trying to use `cmake` for a project of mine.
The structure of it is pretty trivial, consisting of main folder and a 'library' subfolder also containing headers and source files:

```
./            sourceA.cpp ...
./lib/        sourceB.cpp headerB.cpp ...
```

I wish to let the user define some constants which then should be used by the preprocessor to replace some placeholders, like: `char data[DIMENSION]`

In in the main directory I use the following CMakeLists.txt to ask for the value and set it:

```
...
set(DATASET_DIMENSION "4" CACHE STRING "The dimensions of the dataset used.")
set_property(
    GLOBAL
    PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS DIMENSION=${DATASET_DIMENSION}
    APPEND
)
add_subdirectory(lib)
...
```

In the subdirectory, the CMakeLists.txt mainly adds the source files and calls `add_library(lib ${lib_SOURCES})`.

**The problem**: If I execute `make`, the compiler complains that the `DIMENSION` has not been replaced:

```
.../lib/someheader.h:7:19:error: ‘DIMENSION’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

What is wrong with my configuration? I tried to follow the examples of cmake where they specify (my emphasis):

> CMake when executed in the top-level directory will process the CMakeLists.txt file and then descend into the listed subdirectories. **Variables**, include paths, library paths, etc. **are inherited**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do the following in your main CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions(-DDIMENSION=${DATASET_DIMENSION})
```

The problem with yours is that `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` is not [a property of global scope](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#section_PropertiesofGlobalScope), so setting this has no effect.  You're maybe mixing this up with the [directory-scope property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_dir%3aCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS)?